# I want to erase 'class' with several things

Tags: python

I want to erase `class` with several things while scraping.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "script">
   Text<br>
   <div class = "in" number="1"></div>
   <div class = "in" number="2"></div>
</div>
```

**I Try This (failed):**

```
refine = html.find('div', attrs={'class': 'in'})
for refine in html:
    refine_com = str(script).replace(str(refine),"")

print(refine_com)
```

**I want as result:**

```
<div class = "script">
   Text<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
spam = """<div class = "script">
   Text<br>
   <div class = "in" number="1"></div>
   <div class = "in" number="2"></div>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(spam, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'in'}):
    tag.decompose()

    # or
    # tag.extract()
print(soup)
```

output

```
<div class="script">
   Text<br/>


</div>
```

Comment: Thak you for your help...!!